# backbone.js - problem loading using models defined in separate file

Tags: sinatra, backbone.js

I'm running [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) with Backbone.js. I'm trying to split up my models, views, etc so they aren't all lumped into a single JS file. Right now I have the following.

*index.html*

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/models.js"></script>

  ...
```

*models.js*

```
Models = {

  var Event = Backbone.Model.extend({

  });


  var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/events',
    model: Event
  });

};
```

So models.js expects that Backbone.js has been loaded, which it should have been based on index.html, however, I'm getting a JavaScript error in models.js where I reference Backbone.Model.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't valid javascript.  Something like this is more likely to work :

```
Models = {}

Models.Event = Backbone.Model.extend({

});


Models.Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/events',
  model: Event
});
```